# LWJGL: Creating a semi Transparent Rectangle and then adding a Rectangle with a texture over it

Tags: java, lwjgl

Im trying to do what's described in the title, heres my code so far but all it does is create the rect with the texture but not the semi transparent one that should appear behind it:

```
public static void draw(){




glPushMatrix();
Game.res.pauseTexture.bind();


GL11.glColor4f(0,0, 0 , 0.5F);

glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
{


    glVertex2f(0, 0);



    glVertex2f(Game.WINX,0 );


    glVertex2f(Game.WINX, Game.WINY);


    glVertex2f(0, Game.WINY);
}

glEnd();
GL11.glColor3f(1,1, 1);

GL11.glTranslatef(Game.WINX/2 - 250, Game.WINY/2 - 350, 0);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);


glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
{

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);


    glTexCoord2f(Game.res.pauseTexture.getWidth(), 0);
    glVertex2f(500,0 );

    glTexCoord2f(Game.res.pauseTexture.getWidth(), Game.res.pauseTexture.getHeight());
    glVertex2f(500, 700);

    glTexCoord2f(0, Game.res.pauseTexture.getHeight());
    glVertex2f(0, 700);
}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

}

I would be happy if someone could tell me the solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Like [this](http://krakendevelopments.appspot.com/res/images/Storage/reference.jpg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, then what you need to do is enable blending and tell OpenGL to blend using the alpha channels.

So you need to add the following where you initialize OpenGL states. You can of course just add it to the rendering loop itself, though the less use of OpenGL calls the better.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

If you have some things you don't want to get affected by transparency/opacity then you just need to disable the blending, like so.

```
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
... render stuff ...
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
... render stuff ...
```

Incase you don't statically import the different classes then here is the same code though with its classes.

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
...
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
```